# Testing a POST that uses Flask-WTF validate_on_submit

Tags: python, python-2.7, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am stumped on testing a POST to add a category to the database where I've used Flask_WTF for validation and CSRF protection.  For the CRUD operations pm my website. I've used Flask, Flask_WTF and Flask-SQLAlchemy. It is my first independent project, and I find myself a little at a lost on how to test the Flask-WTForm validate_on_submit function.

Here's are the models:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True)

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
    users_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Here's the form:

```
class CategoryForm(Form):
    name = StringField(
        'Name', [validators.Length(min=4, max=250, message="name problem")])
```

And here's the controller:

```
@category.route('/category/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def addCategory():
    """ Add a new category.
        Returns: Redirect Home.
    """
    # Initiate the form.
    form = CategoryForm()
    # On POST of a valid form, add the new category.
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        category = Category(
            form.name.data, login_session['users_id'])
        db.session.add(category)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New Category %s Successfully Created' % category.name)
        return redirect(url_for('category.showHome'))
    else:
        # Render the form to add the category.
        return render_template('newCategory.html', form=form)
```

How do I write a test for the if statement with the validate_on_submit function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using py.test and a conftest.py recommended by [Delightful testing with pytest and SQLAlchemy](http://alexmic.net/flask-sqlalchemy-pytest/), here's a test that confirms the added category.

```
def test_add_category_post(app, session):
    """Does add category post a new category?"""
    TESTEMAIL = "test@test.org"
    TESTUSER = "Joe Test"
    user = Users.query.filter(Users.email==TESTEMAIL).first()
    category = Category(name="Added Category", users_id=user.id)
    form = CategoryForm(formdata=None, obj=category)
    with app.test_client() as c:
        with c.session_transaction() as sess:
            sess['email'] = TESTEMAIL
            sess['username'] = TESTUSER 
            sess['users_id'] = user.id
            response = c.post(
                '/category/add', data=form.data, follow_redirects=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    added_category = Category.query.filter(
        Category.name=="Added Category").first()
    assert added_category
    session.delete(added_category)
    session.commit()
```

Note that the new category is assigned to a variable and then used to create a form. The form's data is used in the post.

Comment: I had unnecessarily mystified how the WTForm class worked. After reviewing the source of Flask-WTF and WTFrom, I was able to clarify that Flask-WTF's validate_on_submit() is simply Flask-WTF's is_submitted() and WTForm validate(). is_submitted() checks for the response and the POST or PUT method.

Comment: I'd appreciate input from a more expert user. Is putting the category into the form and then using the form as post data unnecessary? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd also appreciate more input from expert users. I am about to start writing exactly these sort of tests, and my suspicion is that you do _not_ need to use the actual form to create the `POST` data, but I can imagine it might make things _easier_. I am going to test this question out by simply printing the request `POST` data during a normal route use (i.e., adding `print(request.form)` to the actual route), but my suspicion is that it will just be contained in easily identifiable variables according to the WTForm variable naming conventions. Will report back after testing.

Comment: Premature report: The data in `request.form` is contained in an `ImmutableMultiDict`, an object with which I am not familiar but will read the documentation on. One thing I will note, however, is that the `csrf` token may present a challenge for not using the WTF form. Since you use the `validate_on_submit()` method I will assume that you _are_ using the `csrf` token so I imagine that the token is already generated in the post data. Without the form, my suspicion is, you will not have a `csrf` token and you will not properly validate. Will investigate further.

Comment: Belated update: a regular dictionary works just fine. The CSRF token is an issue, but there are separate answers to that precise question (not all of the solutions always work).

Answer (score 6):

You should have different configurations for your app, depending if you are local / in production / executing unit tests. One configuration you can set is

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

See [flask-wtforms documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).

Comment: I've set this attribute as you've mentioned here, but it's not working for me. If you'd like, please find the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68017992/flask-validate-on-submit-returns-false-even-when-wtf-csrf-enabled-is-set-to-fa

Comment: Although helpful, this does not answer the question..

Answer (score 0):

Working on the comments of @mas I got to this solution which worked for me:

```
topic_name = "test_topic"
response = fixt_client_logged_in.post('/create', data={"value":topic_name}, follow_redirects=True)
```

I am using this form class:

```
class SimpleSubmitForm(FlaskForm):
    value = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField()
```

In this html file:

```
{{form.hidden_tag()}}

{{form.value.label("Topic", class="form-label")}}
{{form.value(value=topic_name, class="form-control")}}
<br/>
{{form.submit(value="submit", class="btn btn-primary")}}
```

Note that I am using the hidden_tag for the CSRF security, however when testing I have this extra line that de-activates it:

```
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED']=False
```

I have no idea how it actually works under the hood but my hypothesis is this: The wtform FlaskForm object looks at the "data" attribute of the request, which should be a dict. It then looks for keys in that dict that have the same name as its attributes. If it finds a key with the same name then it assigns that value to its attribute.