# Flask-WTF - Unable to test a form submission

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I would like to test a wtf-form with a crsf token but I don't know how to send the token.

**Here is my form :**

```
class myLoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField()
    password = StringField()
    mySubmit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**Here is my route :**

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    loginForm = myLoginForm()

    if loginForm.validate_on_submit():
        result = request.form
        username = result.get("username")
        password = result.get("password")
```

**Here is my test :**

```
import unittest
from flask_testing import TestCase
from flask import Flask
import json

class TestLogin(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        return app

    def test_submission(self):
        headers = {
            'ContentType': 'application/json',
            'dataType': 'json'
        }
        data = {
            'username': 'foo',
            'password': 'bar'
        }

        response = app.test_client().post(
            '/login',
            data=json.dumps(data),
            content_type='application/json',
            follow_redirects=True
        )

        assert self.get_context_variable("loginForm").validate_on_submit() == True
```

The assertion fails, because the validate_on_submit() returns False. I think it is due to the crsf token.

**How can I send the crsf token to the POST request ?**

Have a nice day

Comment: There is a related topic here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579411/testing-a-post-that-uses-flask-wtf-validate-on-submit but it seems the answer doesn't contain any CRSF Token

Comment: disable CSRF functionality for unit tests - see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624060/flask-disable-csrf-in-unittest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you.
[Make it easier to access a CSRF token in automated tests](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/227)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I wonder if there is something more "native". In this answer, some of the class are a outdated which is a bit painfull

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to [test actual CSRF protection in Flask-WTF](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/tree/master/tests) it's much simpler to turn off CSRF completely in app config when running unit tests. The conditions that trigger CSRF protection may be easier tested with integration/e2e tests.